# hid or show div boxes with two drop down lists

Tags: javascript, html

hi in my contact form i have two dropdown list which  div boxes in the form, are hid or shown based on drop down  values. the problem is i can not manage both of them.the first drop down "class=color" works properly but when i select the second drop down  "class=ddcolor" instead of showing "red box" it causes to hide the whole "redd box". it is a little hard to explain in word but i send my whole code. please help. thank you

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!--hide/show div based on dropdown selection-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/hid_show_div.js"></script>
<script src="js/main_hid_show.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
   <fieldset>
   <p dir="rtl"><label>case1</label>
            <select  id="Color" required="required">
            <option>please select</option>
            <option value="redd">home<option>
            <option value="greenn">car</option>
            </select></p>
       </fieldset>
            </div>
<div class="redd box"> 
            <div>
   <fieldset>
   <p dir="rtl"><label>case2</label>
            <select  id="ddColor" required="required">
            <option>please select</option>
            <option value="red">sell<option>
            <option value="green">rent</option>
            </select></p>
       </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="red box">   
           </div>
           <div class="green box">   
              </div>
    
</div>
<div class="greenn box">   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
main_hid_show.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Color").change(function () {
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="redd"){
                $(".box").not(".redd").hide();
                $(".redd").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="greenn"){
                $(".box").not(".greenn").hide();
                $(".greenn").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```js
hid_show_div.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ddColor").change(function () {
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".box").not(".red").hide();
                $(".red").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                $(".box").not(".green").hide();
                $(".green").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you have the 'box' class for both the outer `.redd` and `.greenn` classes as well as the inner `.red` and `.green` classes. This makes the outer `.redd` hide when you select `.red` option because that is a element with class 'box' without class 'red'.

It should work if you rename inner classes to `.inner-box` and then update the jquery to:

```
 $("#ddColor").change(function () {
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".inner-box").not(".red").hide();
                $(".red").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                $(".inner-box").not(".green").hide();
                $(".green").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".inner-box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wme028os/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add another class to the `redd box` and include that in your jQuery `not` selector:

```
<div class="redd box keepme">
```

...and:

```
$(".box").not(".red,.keepme").hide();
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsbin.com/coropufora/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: thank you very much for your answering.  i really appreciate